# Trouble implementing logout from laravel application when user logs out from drupal application

Tags: laravel, drupal, oauth-2.0, laravel-passport

I already have an application built in drupal7. I am building a new extension of the application in laravel. The situation here is, I want to have drupal7 as the base application where the user logs in. I have implemented login using [Oauth2-server](https://www.drupal.org/project/oauth2_server) module in drupal. In this set up after logging in to drupal app, I was able to successfully navigate to laravel and the user will be shown as logged in, also was able get some custom jwt I have exchange to laravel. 
My issue is regarding logging out. How will I implement logout in this case: I want the user to be logged out from laravel app upon logging out of drupal app.

I have added a hook to delete the user's refresh token when the user logs out, but this wont help until laravel checks for a refresh token.

I want the user to be logged out instantly from laravel app upon logging out of drupal app.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to do this with adding another API call to the Laravel side and managed to logout the user when user logs out from Drupal side corresponding to the user id and token.